# Windows Firewall service - Safe to disable?

Tags: windows-xp, firewall, services

I installed Comodo Firewall on my Windows XP 32bit and it turned off the Windows Firewall like  these softwares usually do. However the Windows Firewall/ICS service is still on Automatic and Started. Is it okay to **Disable** it or should I expect side effects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can but you will no longer be able to share an internet connection on the PC with other PCs on your local network. it is not recommended to disable the service, if Windows Firewall is disabled in Control Panel, this is good enough.

> This service was named Internet Connection Firewall/Internet Connection Sharing with Service Pack 1a. It is used to allow multiple computers on your network to access the internet via only one account. This service installs on the "modem" computer. It also provides a software firewall for the system. If you are using a third party firewall, hardware gateway/router or Internet Connection Sharing software package, this service is not required. However, if you are only using a modem and not a hardware firewall/router/gateway, I strongly recommend to keep this service in Automatic.

http://wiki.blackviper.com/wiki/Windows_Firewall/Internet_Connection_Sharing_(ICS)

.